# Retrieve data from SQL Server database using ajax method C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, ajax

I'm new to C# and javacript. I'm doing my first program on Visual Studio and I have one problem to retrieve data from a SQL Server database.

I want to retrieve data from SQL Server and convert it to Json by using an ajax method. But when I start my web page I can see only the table empty, so I think I have not a good method to connect to my data base.

Here is the code for my `WebMethod` used to retrieve data and convert to Json:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Web.Services;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{    
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {                         
    }

    [WebMethod]
    public static string LoadData()
    {
        string strcon = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strcon);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from kit", con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);            
        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ds.Tables[0]); 
    }
```

Please I need your Help I have done several days on this program. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: in addition to what @DevSlick has said below in his answer, any reason why you want to give back a bloated ungeneric object? Best practice: Map the data to a concrete type and return that back to the caller

Comment: Thanks for your help @Ahmed ilyas but can you help me by showing how to map data to a concrete type? I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your CommandType should be Text and not StoredProcedure since you are using a string SQL command and not a Stored Procedure.